# AES encryption of 16 bytes without padding

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

This should be a simple question, but I can't find any examples or figure out the answer from the openssl docs.

I want to encrypt **exactly** 128 bits, which should fit in one encryption block.

So I call `EVP_EncyptInit_ex`, and then what?

Do I call `EVP_EncryptUpdate_ex` (to encrypt the 128 bit block) and `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` (even though there is nothing more left to encrypt)?

Or only `EVP_EncryptUpdate_ex`?
Or only `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you have already figured out the steps.
So, it will be

1. EVP_encryptInit_ex
2. EVP_EncryptUpdate_ex
3. EVP_EncryptFinal_ex

`EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` also take care of the fact that data is not in multiple of block lengths.

In my opinion, if you have only to use AES with no padding (EVP_ interfaces takes care of padding), then go for `AES_encrypt`.

They are fairly easy to use.

```
//Step 1: Set encrypt key.
AES_KEY aeskey;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, bits, &aeskey);
//Step2: Encrypt exactly 128 bits.
AES_encrypt(data, dataout, &aeskey);
```

Comment: Still, I have covered that part.

Answer (score 2):

> AES encryption of 16 bytes without padding

Use the `EVP_*` interfaces and disable padding on the block.

Use the `EVP_*` interface because it supports engines and hardware acceleration, like AES-NI. The `AES_encrypt` functions are software based and do not support alternate implementations. Also, its not readily apparent, but `AES_encrypt` is not portable - some platforms suffer endianess issues.

You need to call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding` to ensure no padding is added. From the [`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html) man page:

> EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding() enables or disables padding. By default
>   encryption operations are padded using standard block padding and the
>   padding is checked and removed when decrypting. If the pad parameter
>   is zero then no padding is performed, the total amount of data
>   encrypted or decrypted must then be a multiple of the block size or an
>   error will occur.
>   This function should be called after the context is set up for 
>   encryption or decryption with EVP_EncryptInit_ex().

So your steps are:

1. Call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new` to create a context
2. Call `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` with the context
3. Call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding` on the context
4. Call `EVP_EncryptUpdate_ex` to encrypt the data
5. Call `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex` to retrieve the cipher text

Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: to add a comment to this as I've just tried, step 2 and 3 need to be flipped as per the docs.

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding() enables or disables padding. This function should be called after the context is set up for encryption or decryption with EVP_EncryptInit_ex()